My AC makes whooshing sound and deep cleaning fixes it. But it reoccurs within few months
The air conditioner in my bedroom is a Fujitsu General ASGA-18SEFT 1.5 ton. FYI I live in a hot and humid weather. For the last few months I am facing a weird issue with it. In March 2023, i noticed the indoor unit is making a whooshing sound (kind of like the wind makes during storm). It also stopped cooling the room down to the set temperature. When turned on, it blows cool air for 15-20 minutes, then the compressor turns off and stop blowing cool air.
So I called up the support and upon inspecting, they told me that the indoor unit is clogged with dirt, so it needs deep cleaning/servicing. So they did a thorough cleaning upon dismantling the exterior part of the indoor unit. They cleaned the blower, coils and what not. So after that my AC was good as new. It was cooling the room as its intended to do for as long as i wanted.
But that didn't last long. 4 months later, the same problem returned. Whooshing sound and shortened cooling period. I called them up again, they said it's clogged with dirt again and need servicing/cleaning. So I asked them to do that again and as usual the AC was good as new.
Surprisingly, same problem reoccurred, this time just after two months. Same issue. This time they checked the internal components of the indoor unit thoroughly and said there is nothing wrong there. They did cleaning again and AC was good as new as usual.
Thing is every time they did deep cleaning, there was not much dirt that came out and surely that litamount of dirt could not have possibly get in the way of blowing cool air properly. But i think whatever small amount of dirt was accumulating, it must have been affecting something inside the unit, which has been causing this issue. Because the problem kept going away every time after deep cleaning was performed. It's also to me mentioned that I don't use the AC longer than 6-7 hours a day.
Is there any experts out there who can suggest me what could be the potential issue that is causing this issue?

Your indoor unit has filters. Do you clean them? https://www.manualslib.com/manual/3369032/Fujitsu-General-Asga18seft.html?page=13#manual

Yes I clean the filters every 2/3 weeks by spraying water with high pressure hand shower. I don’t use any soap or detergent though

The outdoor unit presumably has fins close together that are getting clogged with something.  Is there vegetation near it that releases "fuzzy stuff" (e.g., pollen or petals)?  Heavy mold?  got any pix of the fins?  FWIW, I had to set up window screens to filter the air to mine because the air passed over exposed fiberglass insulation (used for sound isolation)

There is no vegetation near the outdoor unit. But I don’t think the outdoor unit is the culprit here. Because everytime they clean the indoor unit thoroughly the problem goes away for a while
